# Getting an error: "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required" when used map function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
characters = [num for num in range(20, 41)]
mapper = list(map(chr, characters))

print (mapper)      # returning the list of all the ASCII characters w.r.t its value.

mapper = dict(map(chr, characters)) 
print(mapper)
```

In the above code, when I print 'mapper' converted to list object. I am getting the correct output. But when the same is converted to dictionary object. I am getting an error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    mapper = dict(map(chr, characters))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

So, does that mean that map function can only covert into object type- tuple or list and NOT dictionary?

The result I am expecting is where ASCII value to be the dictionary 'keys' and the respective ASCII character as dictionary 'values' something like this:

```
{20: "\x14", 21: "\x15", 22: "\x16", ............ , 39: " ' ", 40: " ( "}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you really want to use `map`, you can, but as @e4c5 stated: "that would be inelegant, more lines of code, unpythonic and slower", which is entirely true. But I'll provide an example using `map` for you, since that's what you seemed to want:

The reason your code doesn't work is because a dictionary needs a key and a value, right now, you only the `value`, no `keys`. You can use `zip` to zip the key from `characters` to the value from `map`:

```
characters = [num for num in range(20, 41)]    
mapper = dict(zip(characters,map(chr, characters)))
print(mapper)
```

Comment: Just one more question @abccd. In what all context this error generally appears. Reason I'm asking, is because in case of a lengthy codes, how can I ballpark the line(s) of code that is giving this error.?

Comment: For example: dict([1,2,3,4]) will give you the error since everything separated by a comma only has one value, dict needs a key-value pair. dict([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)]) will be fine because everything separated by a command has two values, 1 and 2, 3 and 4...the first value will become the key and the second will become the value. In general, you will need to make sure nothing that you're trying to convert to dict has only one value.

Comment: Thanks again @abccd for the generous answer.

Answer (score 2):

Was this what you were looking for?

```
mapper = { num:chr(num) for num in range(20,41) }
```

it produces a dictionary where the keys are numbers are values are the letters. Perhaps you wanted it the other way round?

```
mapper = { chr(num):num for num in range(20,41) }
```

Comment: Thanks @e4c5 for answering. result obtained from your code is what I am looking for. But, is it not possible to have one such result using map() function. ?

Comment: that would be inelegant, more lines of code, unpythonic and slower

Comment: Ahh.. okay. Thanks for your inputs. :)

Comment: I am sorry I am new to Stackover flow, might have clicked somewhere accidentally

Comment: Ah I see your problem, you had accepted the other answer earlier and now that is unaccepted.  You can only accept one answer at a time, if you like the other answer better, please do accept it. That's perfectly all right.

Comment: yeah I remember that I tried clicking both the answer as 'Accepted' and previous selection go off. I agree that both the expert users gave me useful information and in essence I accept both of them. But website restrict me to choose multiple.

Comment: Exactly, that's the situation, for which they created, upvotes. Here one from me to give you the hang of it.

Comment: So please do feel free to give to upvotes to both answers if you like them both